# svn delete all sub-dirs with the same name

Tags: svn

I accidentally checked in code which was stored in CVS to SVN without removing the CVS folder.
How do I svn delete them at the same time? 
find -name "DIRNAME"-exec rm -rf {} \; will remove only the DIRS locally.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the same command with [`svn delete`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html) instead of `rm -rf`, then commit.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying a pipe to svn delete first and it not work. Now this works.